# REST Service not enabled in Bigip 12

Tags: f5, big-ip

I have BigIP VE 12.1 installed and activated with lab licence. I couldn't access it using Rest API. I researched questions related this and checked "service **restjavad** it is running fine still rest calls not getting any response. someone please help on enabling the Rest services

Comment: F5 still provides general assistance support on lab VE's.  Put a ticket in with F5 Support.

Comment: how are you trying to access it? Do you have any debug data?

Comment: I tried to hit it from rest client it is not giving any response. after searching solution in internet i came to know it all on "I-Control Rest Deamon Service" when am searching for that service in TMSH I am getting "couldn't find ICRD Service" error

Answer (score 2):

What is the response to:

```
tmsh show sys service icrd
```

If you get "Service icrd has not been added to big start." Then you need to execute:

```
modify sys service iced add
```

'icrd' is the iControl REST daemon.

This will ensure that 'icrd' autoloads during BIG-IP boot-up. Hope that helps.